# How to handle character encoding correctly in MySQL 8.0?

Tags: sql, mysql, character-encoding

I'm simply trying to create a new table and import some values into it, but I have an encoding issue that I can't seem to figure out.

Here is the `character_set` and `collation` information regarding my environment:

```sql
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                           |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | cp850                                           |
| character_set_connection | cp850                                           |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                          |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                          |
| character_set_results    | cp850                                           |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                                         |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                                         |
| character_sets_dir       | c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.31\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'coll%';
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | cp850_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I also have a `test.sql` which contains:

```sql
SET default_storage_engine=INNODB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `chapitres`;

CREATE TABLE chapitres (
  id TINYINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  titre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO chapitres
  (id, titre)
VALUES
  ('1', 'é');
```

If I import `test.sql` file as follows:

```sql
mysql> source test.sql
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

I don't have the desired result:

```sql
mysql> select * from chapitres;
+----+-------+
| id | titre |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Ú     |
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I was expecting an `é` and I got a `Ú`. Can you help me understand what I'm missing? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The variables you listed imply that the _client_ is giving text encoded in cp850.  MySQL will convert to/from the latin1 of capitres.titre when doing `INSERT/SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing a bit further, I noticed that `é` is encoded as `0082` in cp850. This corresponds to `00E9` in both `ISO 8859-1` and `UTF-8` and `Ù` is `00E9` in `cp850`.

I managed to solve my issue by encoding `test.sql` in `cp850` or simply by copy/pasting its contents as an SQL statement in DBeaver.

I'm not sure why the `character_set_client` and `character_set_connection` are set to `cp850`, it could be a Windows default, but I'm not ready to venture down that rabbit hole just yet. :)